# Validate second column is sorted for first column duplicates

Tags: c#, list, selenium, sorting

I have two columns with identical row count, column 1 is `FirstName` and column 2 is `LastName`. I do multiple sorts by sorting the first column ascending, then sort the second column ascending based on the duplicates of the first column. How do I validate that where there are duplicate entries in column 1 column 2 of the same index are sorted correctly See image for example
[input and output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBYlK.png)

```
  List<string> firstName = new List<string> { "Steve", "John", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob" };
  List<string> lastName = new List<string>  { "John", "Bryant", "Paul", "David", "Apple" };
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Please, *don't split* the *single* entity (`Name`) into *several* collections (`firstName`, `lastName`).

Let's *combine* them back to single `names` with a help of *Linq* `Zip`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var names = firstName
  .Zip(lastName, (first, last) => new { 
     first,
     last 
   })
  .OrderBy(name => name.first) // by first name ascending
  .ThenBy(name => name.last)   // in case of tie by last name ascending
  .ToArray();

// Let's have a look:
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, names
  .Select(name => $"{name.first} {name.last}")));

// If you insist on splitting names back to 2 lists:

firstName = names
  .Select(name => name.first)
  .ToList(); 

lastName = names
  .Select(name => name.last)
  .ToList();
```

**Edit:** Having the correct order (`names`) implemented we can *validate* the orders provided:

```
 // Orders to be tested 
 IEnumerable<string> firstNameUnderTest = ...
 IEnumerable<string> lastNameUnderTest = ...

 var counterExamples = names
   .Zip(firstNameUnderTest, (name, fn) => new {name, fn})
   .Zip(lastNameUnderTest, (item, ln) => new {
      expectedFirst = item.name.first,
      expectedLast  = item.name.last,
      actualFirst   = item.fn,
      actualLast    = ln     
    })
   .Where(item => item.expectedFirst != item.actualFirst ||
                  item.expectedLast != item.actualLast)
   .Select(item => $"Expected: {item.expectedFirst}, {item.expectedLast}; " +
                   $"Actual: {item.actualFirst}, {item.actualLast}")
   .ToArray();
```

Let's have a look at `counterExamples`:

```
 Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, counterExamples));
```

You can want to put `counterExamples.Any()` to check if there's at least one failed test, `counterExamples.Count()` to count failed tests etc.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful when it comes to figuring out a good way to combine both columns. But, the original question was, how do I **validate** that the second column is sorted correctly?Not visual test validation. I want to write the logic

Comment: I want to assert that all names.last in the same position as a names.first duplicate is sorted correctly. For instance, for all the first names Bob validate that there last name is sorted